# NetSuite Client Script 2.0 to Disable Expiry Date Sublist Field on Inventory Detail record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, clientscript, suitescript1.0

I'm trying to disable the display type of expiry date field on inventory details. The current client script is working for 1st line only or 0 index. I'm trying to completely disable this field for all lines while adding inventory details.

This is my script please tell me what I missed here.

Thanks

```
function lineInit(scriptContext) {
        try {
            var currentRecord = scriptContext.currentRecord;
            var sublistId = scriptContext.sublistId;

            if (sublistId !== 'item') return;

            var selectedLine = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistIndex({
                sublistId: 'item'
            });

            log.debug({ title: 'selectedLine', details: JSON.stringify(selectedLine) });

            var inventoryDetail = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistSubrecord({
                sublistId: "item",
                fieldId: "inventorydetail"
            });

            var expiryDate = inventoryDetail.getCurrentSublistField({
                sublistId: "inventoryassignment",
                fieldId: "expirationdate"
            });

            expiryDate.isDisabled = true;

        } catch (error) {
            log.debug({ title: 'Catch Error', details: error });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to traverse the loop using

var numLines = objRecord.getLineCount({
sublistId: 'item'
});

for the inventory detail sublist (summary) similarly as we do for item sublist then only it will set all the expiry dates to disabled , you have just taken the index "selectedLine" and printed in the log